# 2D array print sum of elements between first negative number and last of each rows

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can't to solve a problem. How to find a **sum** of elements between first negative number and last **of each rows**? I did it for one dimensional array but I can't to rewrite for two-dimensional array. For two-dimensional array I have always an answer `0`. 
This is example how is it in one dimensional array `[-1, 2, 3, -4]` the answer will be `5` or `[-1, 2, 3, -4, 5]` answer is `5` if we have `[1, -2, 3, -4]` answer is `3`. The same should be in two-dimensional array. How to solve it? Please help me.

This is a code

```
public void another() {

            int a[][] = new int[][] {
                    {-1, 2, 3, -4},
                    {-3, 5, 6, -8},
                    {-9, 2, 3, -1},
                    {-7, 2, 3, -9}};

            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));

            int sum = 0;
            int min = 0; int min_j = 0;
            int kol = 0, firstNeg_i = 0, nextNeg_i = 0;
            int firstNeg_j = 0, nextNeg_j = 0;

            if (a[0][0] < 0) {
                kol++;
                firstNeg_i = 0; firstNeg_j = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                    if (a[min][min_j] > a[i][j]) {
                        min = i;
                        min_j = j;
                    }
                    if ((a[i][j] < 0) && kol < 1) {
                        firstNeg_i = i;
                        firstNeg_j = j;
                        kol++;
                        i++; j++;
                    }

                    if ((a[i][j] < 0) && kol < 2) {
                        nextNeg_i = i; nextNeg_j = j;
                        kol++;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = firstNeg_i + 1; i < nextNeg_i; i++) {
                for (int j = firstNeg_j + 1; j < nextNeg_j; j++) {
                    sum += a[i][j];
                    //System.out.println(sum);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
static int negSum(int[] a)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
  {
    if(a[i] < 0)
    {
      for(int j=i+1; j<a.length && a[j]>=0; j++)
        sum += a[j];
      break;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

If the array contains only a single negative it sums to the end of the array. If you want to return 0 in this case just check if `j == a.length` before the `break` and if so set `sum` to 0.

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int tests[][] = new int[][] {
    {-1, 2, 3, -4},
    {-3, 5, 6,  8},
    {9, 2, 3, -1},
    {-1, 2, 3, -4, 5},
    {1, -2, 3, -4},
    };

    for(int[] test : tests)
      System.out.printf("%s : % d\n",Arrays.toString(test), negSum(test));
}
```

Output:

```
[-1, 2, 3, -4] :  5
[-3, 5, 6, 8] :  19
[9, 2, 3, -1] :  0
[-1, 2, 3, -4, 5] :  5
[1, -2, 3, -4] :  3
```

Comment: Oooh I got it! Just for-each to make like a one dimension array and then sum for each rows. I understood. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely split the function up.

Just use one function that calculates the sum of an array.
Then calculate each sum in the two dimensional array:

```
public void calculateSum() {
    int a[][] = new int[][] { { -1, 2, 3, -4 }, { -3, 5, 6, -8 }, { -9, 2, 3, -1 }, { -7, 2, 3, -9 }};

    int sums[] = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        sums[i] = getSumBetweenNegatives(a[i]);
        System.out.println(sums[i]);
    }
}

public int getSumBetweenNegatives(int[] a) {
    int sum = 0;
    int indexFirstNegative = -1;
    int indexSecondNegative = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0 && indexFirstNegative == -1) {
            indexFirstNegative = i;
        }
        else if (a[i] < 0) {
            indexSecondNegative = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // maybe check if two negatives were found
    for (int i = indexFirstNegative + 1; i < indexSecondNegative; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

if you need the complete sum of a two dimensional array, just sum the result up again